# How change home widget height?

Tags: android, android-widget

Hello :) It's possible to change height of home widget? I know it's normal possible in XML, but I want know its possible in CLASS. For example, I have a widget 40dp height which gives 1 on home, and I want to have in code way to change to 110dp which gives 2 on home. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible.

When dragging a widget into the home screen it takes exactly the width/height specified in the xml.

If what you wanted was possible, what would happen to the widgets arround your widget?

Comment: What is "apk popup widget"?